# Understanding unicode and encoding in Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-2.x

When I enter following in the python 2.7 console

```
>>>'áíóús'
'\xc3\xa1\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xbas'
>>>u'áíóús'
u'\xe1\xed\xf3\xfas'
```

I get the above output. What is the difference between the two? I understand the basics of unicode, and different kind of encoding like UTF8, UTF16 etc. But, I don't understand what is being printed on the console or how to make sense of it.

Comment: The output in python2.7 of `'áíóús'` is `'\xc3\xa1\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xbas'`. Not sure where you get the `dfasdf` at the end.

Comment: @solarc: edited.

Answer (score 4):

`u'áíóús'` is a string of *text*.  What you see echoed in the REPL is the [canonical representation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=repr#func-repr) of that object:

```
>>> print u'áíóús'
áíóús
>>> print repr(u'áíóús')
u'\xe1\xed\xf3\xfas'
```

The things like `\xe1` are related to hexadecimal ordinals of each character:

```
>>> [hex(ord(c)) for c in u'áíóús']
['0xe1', '0xed', '0xf3', '0xfa', '0x73']
```

Only the last character was in the ascii range, i.e. ordinals in `range(128)`, so only that last character "s" is plainly visible in Python 2.x:

```
>>> chr(0x73)
's'
```

`'áíóús'` is a string of *bytes*.  What you see printed is an encoding of the same *text* characters, with your terminal emulator assuming the encoding:

```
>>> 'áíóús'
'\xc3\xa1\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xbas'
>>> u'áíóús'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa1\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xbas'
```